# how to get rid of space when writing data in txt file with PHP_EOL

Tags: php, fwrite

I am writing data to a `.txt` file with linebreaks:

```
// put content in .txt file with linebreaks; unique_id first
        $userinput = $unique_id.PHP_EOL;
        $userinput .= date('d M Y h:i').PHP_EOL;
        $userinput .= $userinput1.PHP_EOL;                                                                              
        $userinput .= $userinput2.PHP_EOL;

        $messagefile = './messages/';
        $messagefile .= $unique_id . '.txt'; //name of the file is the same as unique_id

        // create file in messages folder
        $h = fopen($messagefile, 'w+');
        fwrite($h, html_entity_decode($userinput));
        fclose($h);
```

My .txt file now looks like this:

```
20191103135045 // unique id = date
03 Nov 2019 01:50
John
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

For reading the first line of the `.txt` file, i use this:

```
// get data out of txt file 
    $msg = '../messages/';
    $msg .= $file;
    $fh = fopen($msg, 'r'); 
    $lines = file($msg);// filedata into an array

    $file_id = $lines[0]; // file id
```

Now is use the content of the first line (unique id or date) in a form:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="delete_file" value="<?php echo $file_id; ?>" />
```

When i echo the value of the hidden input field, it says that there is a `space` behind it:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_file'])) {
        $filename = '../messages/'.$_POST['delete_file'].'.txt';
        echo $filename;
```

I was the echo is something like this: `20191103135045.txt`

But it is this: `20191103135045 .txt`

So where is the space between the `5` and `.` coming from?
It has to do something with `PHP_EOL` when i put the content in the `.txt` file?

Comment: Maybe. The question is, what could you do about it? Trim the space using function `trim`

Comment: It seems that the first line is not `20191103135045` but this: `20191103135045 ` So how can i get rid of the space at the end?

Comment: @john use [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Comment: I think it has something to do with PHP_EOL. On windows it's `\r\n` on Linux is `\n`. Try to force the end line to `"\n"`

Comment: You sure you didn't put any space before the quote `value="<?php echo $file_id; ?>"` ?

Comment: yes i am sure. the value is without spaces. I checked it!

Comment: Try `$lines = file($msg, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

Comment: @Nigel I agree,. Now it works fine. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
$lines = file($msg, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) ...

> **FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES**
>
> Omit newline at the end of each array element

without this, there will be the extra characters you see at the end of each row.